# CSS Html Ordered List - Text under number

Tags: html, css

I think it is an easy question. What I need to do is put the text of long lines under the number of the list. Something like this:

1       Text text text text Text text text textText text text textText text text textText text text textText text text textText text text textText text text textText text text textText text text text.

In my code I'm using the following structure:

< ol>
< li>
< p> Text

< /li>
< /ol>

Some simple solution? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
ol {
  list-style-position:inside;
}
```

The default value is `outside`.

### [Demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/pgd8z/3/)

Comment: I used this solution but added an ASCII tab (&emsp;) to give an appearance of a paragraph